# Area target retracking problem using vuforia

Tags: vuforia

Using Vuforia Engine to scan big university buiding, when the app start tracking the environment it displays 3D graphic accordingly, but when i start moving great distance along the buiding corridors, sometimes objects are little bit off their place and when vuforia does a retracking of the environment, it doesnt stick to the new environment tracking but keeps jumping between the old tracking and new tracking of the building, making the rendering of 3D objects also jumps between their new right position and the old off position. How can i make it stick to the new environment tracking and forget the old one in order to have a smooth experience navigating the building.

i tried attaching and detaching the script MultiArea (concerning combining multiple area targets, the building is scanned using 18 area targets attached together) relative to each target area at runtime. so when the engine tracked the area target it is the anchor position to the whole buiding and it sticks to the new tracking but it didnt seem to work.

Comment: Does the building have areas which look very similar to each other? If yes Vuforia Engine can get confused and jump from on location to another. A possible way to solve this is to provide an external prior for example as described here https://developer.vuforia.com/library/develop-area-targets/geolocation-external-prior-area-targets

Comment: From the description looks like there is an issue with the MultiArra script which likely has not been tested with so many targets. Creating a single target might solve the problem, otherwise you will have to modify the MultiArea script to suit your needs.